# How to get sales ranking in PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am stuck in a logic. I want to generate a monthly base ranking of sales. The scenario of my ranking is, different sales man have different boxes to sold, they sold a box and i save there quantity of boxes. Now every person have different id and different no. of boxes sold. Can anyone suggest me how can i rank them?? I am using the code-igniter.
 
And i want to rank them in two different ways (no of boxes sold and amount of sales they generated)

Thanks in advance.

```
$rank = 0;
    $array = array();
    $j =0;
    for($i = 0; $i <count($sales_ranking); $i++){
        $quantity = 0;
        $key = $sales_ranking[$i]->fmid;

        if (in_array($key, $array)) {
            echo "<br>__".$j = $j++;
                continue;

          }else{

              array_push($array, $key);
              $l = $i - $j;
              for($j = 0; $j <count($sales_ranking); $j++){
                  if($sales_ranking[$i]->fmid == $sales_ranking[$j]->fmid){
                      $quantity     = $quantity + $sales_ranking[$j]->qty;
                      $name[$l]     = $this -> sales_rank -> get_name($sales_ranking[$i] -> fmid);
                  }else{
                      continue;
                  }
              }
          }

        $qty[$l] = $quantity;
    }
```

Comment: this can be done directly in sql. post your ddl and sample data